# Spinner double click crashing app

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, android-adapter

I have implemented spinner and its working fine with 'single click'. But when I double click on any item of spinner, whole app is getting crashed. Basically user should be unable to double click. I am running code on emulator. Is this happing due to slow emulator or is there any error in my code?

### MainActivity.java

```
static Spinner statusSpinner;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spn_Status);
        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        //do something
    }

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
        //do something
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <Spinner
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:id="@+id/Spn_Status"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_down"
        android:entries="@array/Status"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:prompt="@string/Set_Status"
       android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.Spinner$DialogPopup.dismiss(Spinner.java:907)
    at android.widget.Spinner$DialogPopup.onClick(Spinner.java:945)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onDetachedFromWindow(AbsListView.java:2670)
    at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:12160)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2570)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:2820)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5162)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3148)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```